# Regex causes duplicates, why?

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to catch all urls inside a @font-face but $matches creates duplicates, which it shouldn't. I really can't figure out at all why this happens. I created the regex with https://regex101.com/ and it works well but it does not work when I put it in a php document myself. Any help is really appreciated!
My php version is 7.1 if that helps!

```
<?php
$re = '/url\s*\(\s*[\'"]?(?!(((?:https?:)?\/\/)|(?:data\:?:)))([^\'"\)]+)[\'"]?\s*\)/';
$str = '@font-face{font-family:Poiret One;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local(\'PoiretOne-Regular\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff2) format(\'woff2\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff) format(\'woff\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf) format(\'truetype\')}@font-face{font-family:Open sans;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local(\'OpenSans-Regular\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont_webfont.woff2) format(\'woff2\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont_webfont.woff) format(\'woff\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format(\'truetype\')}@font-face{font-family:Open sans;font-weight:300;src:local(\'OpenSans-Light\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-light-webfont_webfont.woff2) format(\'woff2\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-light-webfont_webfont.woff) format(\'woff\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf) format(\'truetype\')}@font-face{font-family:Dancing Script;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:local(\'dancing-script_regular\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancingscript-regular_webfont.woff2) format(\'woff2\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancingscript-regular_webfont.woff) format(\'woff\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancing-script_regular_webfont.ttf) format(\'truetype\')}@font-face{font-family:Josefin Slab;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:local(\'JosefinSlab-Regular\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-regular_webfont.woff2) format(\'woff2\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-regular_webfont.woff) format(\'woff\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/JosefinSlab-Regular.ttf) format(\'truetype\')}@font-face{font-family:Josefin Slab;font-weight:400;font-style:italic;src:local(\'JosefinSlab-Italic\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-italic_webfont.woff2) format(\'woff2\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-italic_webfont.woff) format(\'woff\'),url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/JosefinSlab-Italic.ttf) format(\'truetype\')}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

If you ctrl+f and write divi-child you can see that it's stated 18 times in the $str but $matches is 36 times:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff2) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff ) [2] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf ) [3] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont_webfont.woff2) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont_webfont.woff2 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont_webfont.woff) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont_webfont.woff ) [5] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf ) [6] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-light-webfont_webfont.woff2) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-light-webfont_webfont.woff2 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-light-webfont_webfont.woff) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-light-webfont_webfont.woff ) [8] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf ) [9] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancingscript-regular_webfont.woff2) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancingscript-regular_webfont.woff2 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancingscript-regular_webfont.woff) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancingscript-regular_webfont.woff ) [11] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancing-script_regular_webfont.ttf) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/dancing-script_regular_webfont.ttf ) [12] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-regular_webfont.woff2) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-regular_webfont.woff2 ) [13] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-regular_webfont.woff) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-regular_webfont.woff ) [14] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/JosefinSlab-Regular.ttf) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/JosefinSlab-Regular.ttf ) [15] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-italic_webfont.woff2) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-italic_webfont.woff2 ) [16] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-italic_webfont.woff) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/josefinslab-italic_webfont.woff ) [17] => Array ( [0] => url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/JosefinSlab-Italic.ttf) [1] => [2] => [3] => /wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/JosefinSlab-Italic.ttf ) )
```

Comment: It is explained in the [documentation of `preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) does the same: `$matches[0]` contains the substring that matches the entire `regex`, starting from `$matches[1]` there are the substrings that match the [capturing groups](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) present in the `regex`. You can easily spot this if you take a look at the output of `print_r($matches)` in a `<pre>` element (or not embedded in HTML at all).

Comment: Thank you @axiac I used this along with the answer from Luke!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran your code.

I got an array of 18 elements.

The reason your Ctrl+F is returning two instances of "divi-child" is because it is present in the full contents match, and the smaller match you specify with brackets.

```
array (size=18)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff2)' (length=72)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff2' (length=67)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff)' (length=71)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff' (length=66)
<snip>
```

Also, when debugging, [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is a better function - gives you more information about the variable contents.

### Suggested Solution for User

(Rather than trying to squeeze this into comments...)

Change the Regular Expression to

```
$re = '/url\s*\(\s*[\'"]?(?!(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)|(?:data\:?:))([^\'"\)]+)[\'"]?\s*\)/';
```

Change the parameters sent to the `preg_match_all()` function to

```
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

The returned value will be an array with two elements (each arrays in themselves). The first element will be an array of the complete matches to your regular expression. The second element will the the portion of the match which we are capturing with the brackets.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=18)
      0 => string 'url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff2)' (length=72)
      1 => string 'url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff)' (length=71)
      2 => string 'url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf)' (length=62)
      3 => string 'url(/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont_webfont.woff2)' (length=79)
      <snip>
  1 => 
    array (size=18)
      0 => string '/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff2' (length=67)
      1 => string '/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/poiretone-regular_webfont.woff' (length=66)
      2 => string '/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/PoiretOne-Regular.ttf' (length=57)
      3 => string '/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont_webfont.woff2' (length=74)
      <snip>
```

Comment: Hi Luke and thank you for helping me!
How can we only catch the smaller match so we only have 1 instance?

Comment: Use non-greedy quantifiers, like `.*?` As opposed to greedy ones like `[^"]` `.+` etc.

Comment: Please see my answer - I've extended it to include a possible solution for you, @Sneakybastardd